# HTML Formatting in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: html, visual-studio-2008, formatting

Is it possible to turn off all HTML formatting in Visual Studio 2008? It just totally messes everything up. For example, I'll add a grid with columns, styles, etc. with them all indented and on separate lines. I'll switch to design view or split view and all the work I just did is on one line! It is so frustrating.

I've changed some things in the Options menu but is there any way to turn it off completely?

I don't use design view usually. I enter my tags and controls using source view but sometimes I will switch for a second to look at something.

Comment: Argh! It is SO frustrating to wrestle with Visual Studio. I only work in code view, but sometimes you just have to look at design view and you end up with such a mess. Thank you SO much for getting us an answer for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some formatting options under *Tools-->Options-->Text Editor-->HTML-->Format*
while there doesn't seem to be an option to turn it off, there may be something there to define how you want it to format.

To reformat the document hit (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) or *Edit-->Advanced-->Format Document*.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use design view.  A good asp.net developer doesn't need it.  It only brings with it more headaches than benefits.